# Identifying subnets to enable VPC flowlogs in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, audit-logging, google-vpc

We need to enable `VPC Flow logs` in our `GCP` environment. There are around 100 projects and most of services are using `SharedVPC` . Each `SharedVPC` has around three `subnets` and services in many projects are still running under `Default VPC` Because there is a cost associated with `VPC Flow logs` like `storage costs` and `Data access Audit Logs` . So our plan is not to enable `Flow logs`  only on `subnets` which are Internet facing . But there is nothing like `private/public subnet` in `GCP'.

One option we are thinking is like identifying the `subnets` of GCP services which are exposed to Internet or using `Public IP` like `Google Load Balancer` , `VM instances with Public IP` , `GKE LB and Ingress` , `Cloud SQL instances with Public IP` etc and enable `VPC Flow Logs` on these `subnets` . But we have to browse through all the projects to identify the subnets for these services which are exposed using `Public IP`. Does this makes sense ?

There is also options like increasing the `Aggregation internal` and `sample rate` to decrease the cost associated with `VPC flow logs` but I am looking
for guidelines and best practices available to identify `subnets` for enabling `VCP flowlogs`.

Comment: Looks like VPC flowlogs records traffic from only VM instances and VMs associated with GKE. Not used from capturing traffic from Services like Load Balancer , GKE Ingress , Public SQL instances etc . Can somebody please confirm ?

Comment: If you want to scan the traffic from internet to your VM, I thing the firewall logs are more suitable for this. The VPC flow logs only capture the internal VPC traffic.

Comment: @ guillaume blaquiere, I agree with your comments and I think this could be the right answer to address this scenario. I would like to add the [Google Cloud Firewall Rules Logging](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/google-cloud-firewall-rules-logging-how-and-why-you-should-use-it) in this context. I would like to request you to put your comments as a proper answer to this question to help the community .